# PHP long-lasting script and max exec time

Tags: php, synchronization, time-complexity

I need to manage on-server synchronization between a classic database and a big amount of xls files.

If they are synchronized i perform all the operation over DB and have no problems.

Periodically some of these files are added to the server, and i need to synchronize them. They could be few, but very long, order of hundred thousands rows.

If i catch new of them i start a sync procedure. Sync procedure is proven to last short enought to not exceed Maximmum Execution Time that PHP trig after say 30secs **for 1 file**. But when i have more files it's likely to exceed it.

I **can not** override the PHP time limit.

Right now i have a transaction that backroll if last file sync'tion failed.
And have to reload the page untill i see a *sync failed/succeeded* message.
This works, but it is not very nice at all.

Choices:

1. with register_shutdown_function print rest of the page ( possible? ) and tell to reload
2. with a custom script same thing in proximity of time limit
3. Any way to complete the sync in background? and maybe notice it to the page through 
   ajax maybe?

What would be more the suitable choice? is there any 3rd way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nice trick to bypass the time limit, but **it may lag your server** if not done properly. Based on this script, I have written pure PHP CRON alternative.
What do you do is, that you make HTTP client disconnect but you keep script running. This is most important - then, the script can call itself without getting stuck on istelf.
To do this, it is impotant to send http header Content-Length.

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort (true);    //Tells PHP to ignore connection state
ob_start();
echo "Loop started\n";
$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: $size"); //Send exact output size to make sure client disconnects
header("Connection: close");     //Tells client to disconnect
ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();     //Clean all buffers
if(session_id()!="")
  session_write_close(); //Close the session so that the user can use other scripts on the site
/*Here, the script runs even if client is connected*/
?>
```

Now, there is the recursive part **which is very dangerous**. You should make a file, telling the script that it is already running to avoid multiple threads. Like this:

```
if(file_exists("secure_key"))
  exit;
else
  file_put_contents("secure_key",time());
```

Becaus you've said that you are syncing some data, you may need one more file (or MySql table) to store information about synchronisation process. This would make it possible to inform user about request progress, maybe using AJAX, like you wanted. This would make whole application look very professional :)
You may know that, but if it is FOR or WHILE loop, in which you are syncing, it is also great to save start time in constant so you can quit and save without problems:

```
define("STARTTIME",time());  //Right now
define("MAXTIME",ini_get('max_execution_time')); //Max execution time
define("SAFE_EXIT_TIME", 4);  //4 seconds to save & quit

/*preparation*/
while(time()-(STARTTIME-SAFE_EXIT_TIME)<MAXTIME) {
    /*Synchronize*/
}
unlink("secure_key");         //delete the antistuck file
get_headers(/*scriopt url*/); //call itself
exit;                         //quit
```

Comment: Tank you very much, great answer and great Avatar :D 
I'll test it right this evening!

Comment: I must very thank that guy who sugested me that edit with session close. I've spent dreamless night trying to get long poling chat to work, and I was stuck with multiple requests. Now, I finally know why.

Comment: Happy to help - your `session_id()==""` check negates the point of using a session_write_close - the current logic only closes the session if there is no active session. Probably a typo. There is no need to validate before calling session_write_close; [it does not raise any errors or warnings](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/session.c), but if you still want to future proof the code, call it with suppressed warnings, like so: `@session_write_close();`

Comment: You may not believe that, but I have stopped developing that chat 3 years ago because of that problem. Now I've put in one function and everything is all right. That session existence check was just force of habit.